# what is wrong with this code? (to check whether a given number is a prime number)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int a, n, x;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    n > 1;
    a != n && n < a;
    if (a / n == x)
        printf("a is not a prime no");
    else
        printf("a is a prime no");
}
```

If I run this and put a composite number, it still shows it as prime.

Comment: These lines do nothing: `n>1;` and `a!=n&&n<a;`.

Comment: Didn't you forget to, say, code a loop in there? `n` and `x` are not even initialized. Read up about `for`-loops and, well, about basic C in general. Your code makes absolutely no sense, although I guess you want some kind of loop but don't know how or what. In other words: **learn some basic C first**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if` statement is never true duo to `n` and `x` are not initialized. Therefore you only get your else as return. Moreover your expression `n>1;` and `a != n && n < a;` return a bool which is not compered to anything. In that case you need to use a `for` loop.

Here is [a link](http://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/loops/for/) About for loops

```
int main()
{
    int a,n,x = 0;

    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(n=2; n<=a/2; ++n)
    {
        if(a%n==0)
        {
            x=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (x==0)
        printf("",n);
    else
        printf("a is not a prime no");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even if we declare i, the output (when i type in any no.) does not come.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
 int main()
{
    clrscr();//clearing the screen
    int n,x=2,count=0;//Here count is initialised to 0,if it is not prime it remains the same,else it will be equal to 1.You will understand this as you go down
    //A number is a prime number if it is not divisible by any other number from 2 and the number before it.
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(x<n)//As this checking process should continue till the number just preceding it
    {
         if(n%x==0)//checking if the number n is divisible by x or not
         {
             count++;//IF divisible,there is no meaning in continuing,So we are coming out of the loop by incrementing the variable "count"
             break;
         }
         else
         x++;
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        printf("%d is a prime number",n);
        return 0;//Here if number is prime,There is no need to go further and execute till end,To reduce time complexity ,We will write a return statement to stop executing the code.
    }
    printf("%d is not a prime number",n);
    return 0;

}
```